# python get several sub array in one line

Tags: python-3.x, numpy

I have the following :

```
values = np.zeros(50)
for i, (start,stop) in enumerate(zip(index - margin, index + margin)):
    values[i] = np.mean(image[start:stop])
```

where index is a 1d numpy array and margin is an integer. I would like to be able to do the for loop in one line (or at least avoid the for loop) but i cannot figure out how. Indeed, if i do:

```
myArray = np.array([1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9])
indexes = [1,5]
myArray[indexes] # Output : [2,6]
```

it works easily as the goal is to retrieve one element per index. But i want to extract subarrays kind of the same way. is there a solution ?

**EDIT**: here is an short example of what i want. Image is a 1d array like `np.array([1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,11,12,13,14,15,16])`. if i have, say, `index = np.array([5, 10])` and `margin = 1` i expect `output = np.array([[5,6,7],[10,11,12]])` (kind of the same way as if margin would be 0 then i would have `output = np.array([6,11])`)

Comment: Please share an example and expected output

Answer (score 0):

You can use the same idea in a slightly different way:

```
img = np.array([1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,11,12,13,14,15,16])
index = np.array([5, 10])
margin = 1

output = np.array([(img[start:stop+1]) for start, stop in zip(index - margin, index + margin)])
output
array([[ 5,  6,  7],
       [10, 11, 12]])
```

Answer (score 0):

Looks like you want the mean over (selected) moving windows.  For just a few (relative to the overall size), that iteration is probably fine (and fastest).

But there is a moving window trick using `strides`.  One of the imaging packages has a `window` function, which others will cite, but with `numpy` itself:

```
In [204]: x = np.lib.stride_tricks.as_strided(arr,shape=(14,3),strides=(8,8))                                        
In [205]: x                                                                                                          
Out[205]: 
array([[ 1,  2,  3],
       [ 2,  3,  4],
       [ 3,  4,  5],
       [ 4,  5,  6],
       [ 5,  6,  7],
       [ 6,  7,  8],
       [ 7,  8,  9],
       [ 8,  9, 10],
       [ 9, 10, 11],
       [10, 11, 12],
       [11, 12, 13],
       [12, 13, 14],
       [13, 14, 15],
       [14, 15, 16]])
```

from that we can select rows, before or after taking the mean:

```
In [206]: np.mean(x, axis=1)                                                                                         
Out[206]: 
array([ 2.,  3.,  4.,  5.,  6.,  7.,  8.,  9., 10., 11., 12., 13., 14.,
       15.])
In [207]: _[[4,9]]        # 1 offset from [5,10]                                                                                           
Out[207]: array([ 6., 11.])
```

Getting the parameters for `as_strided` right is a bit tricky, requiring a good understanding of array layout.  Actually this is one of the easiest cases, with a 1d array and 1-step.

Note also I avoid the edge cases, where the window would not have full width.

7 wide windows (just change the shape):

```
In [211]: x = np.lib.stride_tricks.as_strided(arr, shape=(10,7), strides=(8,8))                                        
In [212]: x                                                                                                          
Out[212]: 
array([[ 1,  2,  3,  4,  5,  6,  7],
       [ 2,  3,  4,  5,  6,  7,  8],
       [ 3,  4,  5,  6,  7,  8,  9],
       [ 4,  5,  6,  7,  8,  9, 10],
       [ 5,  6,  7,  8,  9, 10, 11],
       [ 6,  7,  8,  9, 10, 11, 12],
       [ 7,  8,  9, 10, 11, 12, 13],
       [ 8,  9, 10, 11, 12, 13, 14],
       [ 9, 10, 11, 12, 13, 14, 15],
       [10, 11, 12, 13, 14, 15, 16]])
```

Comment: Seems great. I actually knew about stride_tricks. but I thaught that there was a simpler solution, a more readable one. If no, i'll take this one. Thanks !